# Css z index in list item dont work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `li` that inside there is a `div` that i want the `div` to be behind the `li` and i use `z-index` and for some reason the `li` box is not on the `div,` only the text becomes above the `div`.

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
li {
  width: 87px;
  height: 69px;
  min-height: 69px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px/3px 3px 2px 2px;
  border-radius: 3px/3px 3px 2px 2px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: solid 1px #96CFFA;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0.4em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
li div.best-value {
  position: absolute;
  height: 96px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FF6700;
  top: -17px;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="best-value">Best Value</div>some text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You realize the `<div>` is children of your `<li>`. So anything you do with your LI will reflect to the child DIV

Comment: You are right there is any solution to this?

Comment: Actually why you use UL LI at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set child element above parent, you have to remove `z-index` from parent and keep negative `z-index` value to the child.

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
li {
  width: 87px;
  height: 69px;
  min-height: 69px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px/3px 3px 2px 2px;
  border-radius: 3px/3px 3px 2px 2px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: solid 1px #96CFFA;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0.4em;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: 1; */
}
li div.best-value {
  position: absolute;
  height: 96px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FF6700;
  top: -17px;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="best-value">Best Value</div>some text</li>
</ul>
```

For more information about stacking context you could check: [MDN - Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).